# Загрузка картинки в альбом одноклассники API

Tags: rest, odnoklassniki-api

Пытаюсь загрузить фотографию в альбом. Сначала проходит авторизация вот такой вот ссылкой

```
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?st.cmd=oAuthAuthorize&st.scope=VALUABLE+ACCESS%3BPHOTO+CONTENT%3BSET+STATUS&st.response_type=code&st.redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2F&st.client_id=91****&tkn=4***
```

Дальше пытаюсь вызвать метод `photosV2.getUploadUrl` и получаю вот такую ошибку

> ( [error_code] => 10 [error_data] => photo content [error_msg] =>
>   PERMISSION_DENIED : User must grant an access to permission 'PHOTO
>   CONTENT' )

Может кто-нибудь что то посоветовать? Либо может кто уже занимался этим

Answer (score 1):

Кроме `VALUABLE ACCESS` нужен так же `PHOTO CONTENT`.
Это права доступа.

Answer (score 0):

В описании ошибки приведена исчерпывающая информация: запрещен доступ к привилегии `PHOTO CONTENT`.

Корректно сформированный запрос еще не гарантирует результата его выполнения. *На другой стороне* (в аккаунте пользователя) вам должно быть *позволено* реализовать ту или иную задачу (т.е. выполнить какой-то код).

Единственный способ реализовать запрос – **делегировать право** (grant permission) на программный доступ к фотографиям.